# Hibernate named query error

Tags: hibernate, named-query

I have a problem with a named query but I don't get it why it doesn't work.

This is how I define the queries:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = Rating.FIND_ALL,
        query = "from Rating"
    ), 

    @NamedQuery(
        name = "getUserRatings",
        query = "SELECT s from Rating s where s.user_id = :user_id"
    )
})
```

and here I use it:

```
public List<Rating> getUserRatings(User user){
    return em.createNamedQuery("getUserRatings", Rating.class).setParameter("user_id", user.getId()).getResultList();
}
```

error: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getUserRatings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NamedQuery cannot have native query.
Check if you have user_id in your entity. user_id  seems like a column in DB.
If so change it to java field

```
SELECT s from Rating s where s.userId = :user_id
```